# Javascript files compared to other languages like C/Java

Tags: javascript

Im creating a project for a job interview to show them my coding style and my basic understanding. My question is I am writing some functions to pull API data and calculate some values based on that data. Often times in other languages I have a main program that runs all my functions that are from another class. However, Im not sure if that common practice for javascript. I was hoping someone could advise me on the subject or a link to an article since Im having trouble finding one. So for example Id have something like this

Scripts.js

```
check connection()

calculateGPA()
```

Someother.js

```
CalcuateGPA()
{
 //math and stuff
}

 checkconnection()
 {
 //test connection
 }
```

is is it better to just have one like so

scripts.js

```
 checkconnection()
 {
  //test connection
 }

 CalculateGPA() 
 {
  // math stuff
 }
```

I'm not entirely sure on when you should have additional files or when to keep functions in other files and make the main one clean that your html page relies on.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this comes down to personal preference, but I usually only separate code when it will be called from multiple pages.

Comment: Thanks. I thought our teacher told me a  few years ago something along the lines of each one being good at one thing. I.E. data info one page, calculations one page. But this is a smaller project and dont feel it really needs more than one. So appreciate the info.

Answer (score -1):

It's depend on your code. If your code is long and complex, you may need to separate it to multiple file, i.e. helpers.js and one main.js for calling those functions in helpers. Otherwise, it may be neater if you combine all your js into one file.

Comment: I dont agree with the -1 fully though I feel the previous response was more well put. I appreciate your time to help out.